# Simple template for calculating Shannon diversity index from FASTQ files with R

Tags: sequence-analysis, microbiome

I have a bunch of files in FASTQ format and need to calculate the Shannon diversity index from all of them.

Is there a simple way to do that with R, some kind of step-by-step recipe?

My problem is not so much finding a function for calculating the index but how to do that on FASTQ files.

Grateful for every hint, Thank you!

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Are you wanting to do the calculation over all the sequences in all the files together, or a separate calculation for each file? 2) Are your sequences already properly aligned, or does alignment need to be part of the solution? Please also note that in this context the Shannon index would only consider counts of different sequences, it would not consider _how different_ the sequences are from each other (e.g. number of SNPs between two sequences doesn't matter, only that they're different).